# Tableau "Who has seen this view" data automation

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

I have a task which requires downloading the data from "Who has seen this view" from multiple dashboards each week, to then prepare a report on weekly activity.

I am trying to find a way to automate this using Python to avoid having to manually download each week, but I can't find a way to do this programmatically without being the organisations administrator (not, I own the dashboards).

My thoughts were to use a web scraper, but I am encountering a hurdle with the companies Okta SSO also.

Is there a way that I can use my open browser (or something that already contains my SSO credentials) to access this data and then download as CSV? I hope this makes sense, appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to query the postgres database that contains all of this data? Seems a lot easier than scraping. Read this if the server admin will give you access to the database: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/using-tableaus-database-build-tableau-server-usage-reports/

Comment: Thanks for this - I will check in with the server admin to see if I can get access. You are right, woulddefinitely be easier!

Answer (score 0):

Had me the same problem week ago.

I tried to make it in a lot of ways with python and API I think that for now there's no way to grab it with python for this moment without using any scraping tools...

In postgres database you might find table view stats and here is everything and
even more which is visible in 'who seen this' in tableau.